# Unable to use search method from googlesearch module in google colab notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, google-search, python-module

```
try: 
    from googlesearch import search 
    
except ImportError:  
    print("No module named 'google' found") 
urls = [] 
for j in search(str(query),tld="com",start=1, num=15, stop=15, pause=0):
        print(j) 
        urls.append(j)
```

I have used the same code in my local Jupyter Notebook. It works. But while executing in google colab notebook it shows me the following error.

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-a97ca791b5a9> in <module>()
      4     print("No module named 'google' found")
      5 urls = []
----> 6 for j in google-search(str(query),tld="com",start=1, num=15, stop=15, pause=0):
      7         print(j)
      8         urls.append(j)

NameError: name 'search' is not defined
```

All the required modules were installed properly.

```
!pip install rake-nltk
!pip install google-search
!pip install google
!pip install urllib
!pip install beautifulsoup4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is here: https://github.com/MarioVilas/googlesearch/issues/39

The problem is related to a name conflict between packages. If you just install `google` and not `google-search`, it will work.

```
!pip install google
```

If you already have them both installed, use:

```
!pip uninstall google-search
!pip uninstall google
!pip install google
```